# Insert a dictionary into SQL database created using JSON in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I have a JSON file from which I read data and get a dictionary I would like this complete dictionary to be inserted into a SQL Server database so that the same can be read as dictionary from the database.

But upon insertion of the same I get an error as below.

> 07/13/2018 11:25:00: ERROR: Exception 102:
> Incorrect syntax near 'camera'.DB-Lib error
>
> Msg 102, severity 15:
> General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server

Below is my `INSERT` query.

```
INSERT INTO hw_info (hostname, peripheralsInfo)
VALUES ('linux-host', '{u'camera': {u'ab': {u'model': u'Model1', u'version': u'Version1', u'selectorMask': u'Data1'}, u'cd': {u'model': u'Model2', u'version': u'Version2', u'selectorMask': u'Data2'}}}')
```

How can this dictionary be inserted into the database?

Comment: You need to escape `'`s inside your sql, by replacing them with 2, so something like `'{u''camera'': {...`

Comment: How is this query built? Using parameters? If you do `json.dumps(your_dict)` and pass that as a parameter into your query, the pymssql lib should do all the necessary escaping for you.

Comment: @JamesZ but isn't the `u` and `'` should not be part of database and directly the json structure should dumped in the database.

Comment: @shmee the `peripheralsInfo` is dumped using an json file e.g device.json and the data is read using `peripheralsInfo = json.loads(open(peripheralsJsonFile).read())` and the query is prepared as `myquery = """INSERT INTO hw_info(hostname, peripheralsInfo) VALUES('%s','%s')""" % (hostname, str(peripheralsInfo))`

Comment: @darth_coder Yes, that means you get a dict from the content of that file. In order to store it in your table, you need to serialize it. Or, if you just want to have the whole json structure, omit the `json.loads()` and take the json string from the file directly. Ah, I see your edit. Yes, just do `peripheralsInfo = open(peripheralsJsonFile).read()` and pass that without the `str()` to your query. In order to use it later in the code you'd `json.loads()` on that field from your SELECT result

Comment: @shmee the last comment of yours has worked for me. Please move the same to answer I will accept the same.

Comment: How about using a blob? In some earlier version of the chrome browser it would store json as a blob in a sqlite database.

Comment: @Marichyasana can you share an example or link to try out.

Comment: @darth_coder There's no point in that, really. BLOBs are used to store **binary** language objects (e.g. images, datastreams), not arbitrary code objects. You'd have to serialize your Python objects to bytes and would store them in a varbinary column at the expense of 4 additional bytes / record. Using the data later on requires deserialization, just as with a json string. You wouldn't gain anything, but lose the human readability of the plain json string in your DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert the json into your database, don't convert it to a Python object; just store the string as read from the file.

```
with open(peripheralsJsonFile).read() as f:
    peripheralsInfo = f.read()

myquery = """INSERT INTO hw_info(hostname, peripheralsInfo) VALUES(%s,%s)""" 

cursor.execute(myquery, (hostname, peripheralsInfo))
```

When you want to use the data in your program later on you would pass the string from the SELECT query through `json.loads()` to make it a Python object.

**EDIT**

Two remarks here.

1. `prefipheralsInfo = open(peripheralsJsonFile).read()` does not close the file properly after reading, hence I used a [context manager](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/) that takes care of that behind the scenes.
2. You format your query string by using Python's string interpolation. That makes your program vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). In my example I make use of a [parameterized query](https://security.openstack.org/guidelines/dg_parameterize-database-queries.html) to circumvent that vulnerability. Parameters also help making sure that your input is passed to your DB as the correct datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is MySql, you try setting the field as TextField and convert the JSON into a string and save it. While retrieving, you can use `ast.literal_eval(fieldName)`.

If you are using PostgreSql you can use the JSONField in models.

Comment: The OP said MS SQL, not MySql. And why do `ast.literal_eval` when you have a json string? `json.loads()` is much more appropriate in that case